# OpenGL 2.0 Drawing with Monodroid (using OpenTK)

Tags: android, opengl-es, xamarin.android, opentk

I'm attempting to setup a cross platform application that uses OpenTK-1.0 to draw some basic 3D objects using the programmable pipeline approach in OpenGL ES 2.0. I have the iOS side of the application working perfectly but the Android facing application keeps hitting `calling unimplemented OpenGL ES API` errors.

I believe this is happening because the Android side of the application is not being setup properly to target OpenGL ES 2.0. I've updated the `AndroidManifest.xml` with the appropriate `<uses-feature>` tag but I'm unable to set `GLContextVersion = GLContextVersion.Gles2_0;` in  the overridden `CreateFrameBuffer()` function for `AndroidGameView`.

For some reason the `GLContextVersion` property doesn't seem to exist in OpenTK version 1.0, but did exist in 0.9.9.3. How do I go about setting the context to target OpenGL ES 2.0 using OpenTK-1.0?

Comment: Encountering the same problem, unable to find a replacement. `GraphicsContextVersion` and `GLVersion` exist, but can't find a way to use either of those.

Comment: The API changed to `ContextRenderingApi = GLVersion.ES`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per Dykam's comment above, the GL context version is now set to handle GL ES 2.0 by using `ContextRenderingApi = GLVersion.ES2;` in `CreateFrameBuffer()`.