# How do I find the origin of a property in C# code?

Tags: c#, f#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to convert the `TexturedCube` [example for monodroid](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/TexturedCube) from C# to F# and hit upon this line of C# code (from the `CreateFrameBuffer` method on the `PaintingView` class):

```
GLContextVersion <- GLContextVersion.Gles1_1
```

In F#, I must be explicit about the origin of `GLContextVersion` but I cannot find it for love nor money. For example, if `PaintingView` implemented an interface that exposed this `GLContextVersion` property then I believe I would have to upcast `this` to that interface type in order to invoke that property.

According to the documentation the `AndroidGameView` (from which `PaintingView` is derived) implements this property but the following fails with `Error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'GLContextVersion' is not defined (FS0039) (TexturedCube)`:

```
base.GLContextVersion <- GLContextVersion.Gles1_1
```

My F# program runs just fine on my Nexus 7 without this line but, as a pedant, I'd like to get this last line translated too!

Comment: You can't "Go to definition" on this?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I tried that and it takes me to `AndroidGameView.GLContextVersion` but that doesn't seem to be accessible from F#.

Answer (score 4):

I've just looked at the code in Xamarin (it has a really neat assembly browser that shows decompiled code!).

It looks to me like that property really doesnt exist in OpenTK-1.0 (referenced by default in the Android OpenGL Sample) and looks to have been superseded(?) by ContextRenderingAPI.

So the code would likely look like

```
base.ContextRenderingApi <- GLVersion.ES1
```

Looking at the source provided for the C# version it is OpenTK and not OpenTK-1.0 referenced, so is likely a breaking API change, rather a C#/F# issue.

Edit:
[OpenGL 2.0 Drawing with Monodroid (using OpenTK)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070872/opengl-2-0-drawing-with-monodroid-using-opentk)
Looks like same issue

Answer (score 3):

Could `GLContextVersion` be protected?

From the F# spec: *Note: The family and protected specifications are not supported in this version of the F# language.*

You could do it using reflection.

As the F# spec mentions that you can access, using Object Expression, protected members during instantiation. If you instantiate using object expression instead of sub-classing it seems to work. An example using Windows Forms:

```
{
    new System.Windows.Forms.Form() with
        override this.CreateControlsInstance() =
            System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlCollection(this)
}
```

Comment: Good idea but how come jump-to-definition takes me to a property on `AndroidGameView` that is `public`? The problem with the object expression is that I apparently need a class with two constructors in order to adhere to the API.